# Set a group of <span>'s position based on the lowest <span> in a table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**EDIT 3** Can I get some more jQuery suggestions please? I've tried so many different CSS options, but Mozilla doesn't seem to want to cooperate, I would like to do something that I know will work...

So I have this 2 row table and I am trying to get the Picture caption to all be at the same height while leaving the picture centered in the `<td>`, and I am thinking that the best way to do this is using jQuery and the `offset()` function. However, I am not really sure about where to get started with this and looping through each `<td>` in the table.

**EDIT:** Trying to keep the images centered in the `<td>` so `vertical-align: bottom` unfortunately won't work...

**EDIT 2:** I also use 2 different styling sheets... one for IE and then one for everything else... the IE is fine, because I can set `position: relative` to my `<td>` and everything still works... the styling sheet for everything else it doesn't work for because in Firefox if I set it to position relative it ends up stacking all of the captions one on top of each other and places it in lala land. So, is there a way to include in a jQuery script `if browser != IE then...`?

I guess here is my mental process in how I want to try and go about doing this...

**Outline:**

For each `<tr>` go through every `<td>`...in each `<td>` get the lowest y position of the span

When there are no more `<td>`'s in the `<tr>` go through the row 1 more time and set all of the spans y position equal to the lowest y position found earlier.

Then go to the next row.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/58u4g/14/

I am a bit ashamed to be putting a fiddle up here without any jQuery code in it especially when I am asking for it, but I have yet to try looping in jQuery, especially looping through the rows of a table... Still doing some research on it, but I figured I would see what all of your thoughts were.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: What if you just set `vertical-align: bottom;` on the `td`?

Comment: Setting `position: relative` to `<td>` instead of `<a>` might help: http://jsfiddle.net/58u4g/15/.

Comment: @VisioN thats a wonderful idea and I REALY wish that works... however if you try the same thing in Mozilla... doesn't work. It ends up positioning all of the captions on top of each other no where near the pictures...

Comment: @Chad another good idea, but then the picture drops to the bottom as well.. Was hoping to keep it centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is probably what you're looking for. I'm sure there are ways to do it with CSS, so don't give up on that yet.

Basically I'm capturing the height of the tallest image in the group and changing all of the images heights to that size. Alternatively, you could make a wrapper around the image and change the height of that, so you don't distort the image dimensions.

**EDIT:** This finds the offset of each span in a row and sets them all equal. See if that works for you (test in chrome/ff)

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var height = 0;
    var $tr = $(this);
    $tr.find('a span').each(function() {
        $(this).offset().top > height ? height = $(this).offset().top : '';
    }).promise().done(function() {
        $tr.find('a span').each(function() {
            $(this).offset({ top: height });
        });
    });
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/58u4g/28/

Comment: Been trying for the past day to find a CSS fix... everything would've been fine had Firefox not come along and mess everything up.

The only problem I have with this answer is that it changes the height of the images... I just took 2 examples from the whole directory, so if I did that for all the images it wouldn't look very good. Is there any way to set the positioning of the spans?

Comment: that is actually perfect. Exactly what I am looking for. Could you explain that code a bit for me please? just for the future so I can replicate @Chad

Comment: Is there a way to search a specific table instead of being general and saying `$('tr').each` like `$('#posiflex_directory tr').each`

Comment: Sure, you can do it just like that. Basically what I did was search through each `tr` to find the span. I took a variable to set at the beginning of each search (`height`) and if the span's offset was greater than the variable height, I updated the variable to reflect the span's offset. Then after the each function had finished looping (`.promise().done()`), I set each row's span offset top to the height variable.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Also, I tried `$('#posiflex_directory tr').each` but it didn't work... what am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Hahaha staring at code all day makes you see things... was using `$('#posifled_directory tr').each` Thanks for all the help Chad!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following for a neater display:

```
#posiflex_directory td {
    width: 215px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px;
    **vertical-align:top**
}
```

And your spans arent acting like absolute. To fix it:

```
#posiflex_directory a {
    color: inherit;
    height: 175px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
```

You will see that all spans will be at the bottom as you want.

Comment: The issue with this being the images are no longer centered.